# call remote webmethod from c#

Tags: c#, asmx, webmethod

I wanted to call a remote webmethod (asmx) from code behind of a page on another server. 
The second requirement is to be able to pass one string and a pdf file to the webmethod and make use of them in the webmethod.

All I have is this simple webmethod in Testing.asmx.

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestPdf()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Can anyone please let me know how to call this webmethod (url: http://mydomain.com/Testing.asmx/TestPdf)?

I would want to pass a pdf file and a string parameter to the webmethod and be able to retrieve it before returning "hello world".

Comment: Have a look at the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Answer (score 0):

For this usage httpget must be enabled.

```
private void DownloadInformation()
{
WebClient Detail = new WebClient();
Detail.DownloadStringCompleted += new        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
Detail.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://link/"));
 }

private static void DownloadStringCallback2 (Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the request was not canceled and did not throw 
    // an exception, display the resource. 
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        string textString = (string)e.Result;

        Console.WriteLine (textString);
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is how do I call this webmethod from codebehind? Secondly, how to pass parameters to the webmethod.

Comment: Do you mean like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224672/how-to-call-a-web-service-method ?